# What should I do to comply with the MVC paradigm?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

Right now, I'm programming in PHP/Laravel, but I think this might apply to any other MVC framework. I'll use PHP/Laravel syntax.

I have an app that will need a very basic audit trail. The audit table (`audit_event`) in the databse is something like:

```
(id, user_id, event_id, description, occured_at)
```

As you guess, the `user_id` is the user that caused the `event_id`. The `description` is here if you need to be more verbose, `occured_at` is the timestamp for the event.

Now, I created an `AuditEvent` model that has the relations to User and Event. I also wrote the relations from `User` and `Event` to `AuditEvent`.

The function to write an audit event is somethin as simple as:

```
public static function audit($event, $description = "") {
    $id = \Auth::user()->id;

    $ae = new AuditEvent();
    $ae->user_id     = $id;
    $ae->event_id    = $event;
    $ae->description = $description;
    $ae->save();

    return null;
}
```

My question is... where should this function be? Should it be in the Model, or should I create a Controller `AuditEventController` and place it there?

When I call the function, I must include

```
use \App\Controllers\AuditEventController
```

and call it

```
AuditEventController::audit(5, "whatever")
```

I know placing the function in the Model will also work, but... what is the correct thing to do to comply with MVC?

Comment: The way I did this was to set up the audit functionality as a service and call it in various event listeners.

Comment: My knowledge of Laravel is not that advanced. Do you have a link to a tutorial or something like that?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't done this in Laravel specifically, so I can only point you to the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers, and https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events. (But really, using this method is just my opinion anyway.)

Comment: I think you're right, because with my method, sometimes I have forgotten to call the function, so yeah, a listener that always works should be a better solution

Comment: As @Don'tPanic said using a service class for this problem seems right IMO. There is no such dedicate place to put your service classess in laravel but I tend to create `app\Services` folder. Dont get confused with ServiceProvider and Service Class they are completely two different things.

Comment: What you want is to implement is called *"event sourcing"*. It's unrelated to MVC. On a completely unrelated subject - it also has nothing to do with Laravel (and other Rails-style RAD frameworks).

Comment: As I said, I got no idea about _event sourcing_ I consider myself pretty novice on Laravel *and* MVC. So if I was implementing it "manually", where should the code be? In that case, it is totally related to MVC's philosophy

Answer (score 0):

How you go about conforming to an MVC architecture is entirely up to you. Laravel does not provide the Model location explicitly so that developers can decide. With that said, since this is something that is going to be doing a CRUD operation it could go in a Model.

You would run your checks in the controller and if everything passed you'd pass a reference to your audit method inside your model.

You mentioned that you need to include **use \App\Controllers\AuditEventController** with it, so then I'd say put this in your controller and create the actual method that saves it in your model.

Comment: To be honest, the main reason to put the function in the Model is to write less. I think is more aesthetical to use shorter words ;-)